# Testing a simple malloc and free implementation

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, malloc

I wrote a 32-bit assembly program to over-ride `malloc` and `free` using `LD_PRELOAD`.

```
        # PURPOSE:  Program to replace malloc and free using LD_PRELOAD
        #
        # NOTES:    The programs using these routines will ask for a certain
        #           size of memory. We actually use more than that size, but we
        #           put it at the beginning, before the pointer we hand back.
        #           We add a Size field and an Available/Unavailable marker. So
        #           the memory looks like this:
        #
        #           #########################################################
        #           #Available Marker#Size of Memory#Actual Memory Locations#
        #           #########################################################
        #                                            ^Returned pointer points
        #                                             here
        #
        #           The pointer we return only points to the actual locations
        #           requested to make it easier for the calling program. It
        #           also allows us to change our structure without the calling
        #           program having to change at all.
        #
        #           The _alloc-lib-test.c program can test it:
        #           Dump the output and read it using hexdump.


        .section .data

# Global variables

# This points to the beginning of the memory we are managing

heap_begin:
        .long 0

# This points to one location past the memory we are managing

current_break:
        .long 0

# Structure information

        .equ HEADER_SIZE, 8       # Size of space for memory region header
        .equ HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET, 0  # Location of the "Available" flag in the
                                  # header
        .equ HDR_SIZE_OFFSET, 4   # Location of the size field in the header

# Constants

        .equ UNAVAILABLE, 0  # This is the number we will use to mark space
                             # that has been given out
        .equ AVAILABLE, 1    # This is the number we will use to mark space
                             # that has been returned, and is available for
                             # giving
        .equ SYS_BRK, 45     # break system call

        .equ LINUX_SYSCALL, 0x80

        .section .text

# Functions

# allocate_init starts

        # PURPOSE:  Call this function to initialize the functions
        #           (specifically, this sets heap_begin and current_break).
        #
        # PARAMS:   None
        #
        # RETURN:   None

        .globl allocate_init
        .type allocate_init,@function

allocate_init:

        pushl %ebp                  # Standard function stuff
        movl  %esp, %ebp

        # If the brk system call is called with 0 in %ebx, it returns the last
        # valid usable address

        movl  $SYS_BRK, %eax        # Find out where the break is
        movl  $0, %ebx
        int   $LINUX_SYSCALL
        incl  %eax                  # %eax now has the last valid address, and
                                    # we want the memory location after that
        movl  %eax, current_break   # Store the current break
        movl  %eax, heap_begin      # Store the current break as our first
                                    # address. This will cause the allocate
                                    # function to get more memory from Linux
                                    # the first time it is run
        movl  %ebp, %esp            # Exit the function
        popl  %ebp
        ret

# allocate_init ends

# allocate starts

        # PURPOSE:  This function is used to grab a section of memory. It
        #           checks to see if there are any free blocks, and, if not,
        #           it asks Linux for a new one.
        #
        # PARAMS:   This function has one parameter - the size of the memory
        #           block we want to allocate
        #
        # RETURN:   This function returns the address of the allocated memory
        #           in %eax. If there is no memory available, it will return 0
        #           in %eax
        #
        #           %ecx - size of the requested memory (first/only parameter)
        #           %eax - current memory region being examined
        #           %ebx - current break position
        #           %edx - size of current memory region
        #
        # We scan through each memory region starting with heap_begin. We look
        # at the size of each one, and if it has been allocated. If it's big
        # enough for the requested size, and its available, it grabs that one.
        # If it does not find a region large enough, it asks Linux for more
        # memory. In that case, it moves current_break up

        .globl malloc
        .type malloc,@function

        # Stack position of the memory size to allocate

        .equ ST_MEM_SIZE, 8

malloc:

        pushl %ebp                     # Standard function stuff
        movl  %esp, %ebp

        movl  $0, %edi
        movl  heap_begin, %eax         # If heap_begin is 0, call allocate_init
        cmpl  %eax, %edi
        je    heap_empty
        jne   heap_nonempty

heap_empty:

        call allocate_init

heap_nonempty:

        movl  ST_MEM_SIZE(%ebp), %ecx  # %ecx will hold the size we are looking
                                       # for (which is the first and only
                                       # parameter)

        movl  heap_begin, %eax         # %eax will hold the current
                                       # search location

        movl  current_break, %ebx      # %ebx will hold the current break

alloc_loop_begin:                      # Here we iterate through each memory
                                       # region

        cmpl  %ebx, %eax               # Need more memory if these are equal
        je    move_to_break

        # Grab the size of this memory

        movl  HDR_SIZE_OFFSET(%eax), %edx

        # If the space is unavailable, go to the next one

        cmpl  $UNAVAILABLE, HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%eax)
        je    next_location

        cmpl  %edx, %ecx               # If the space is available, compare the
        jle   allocate_here            # size to the needed size. If its big
                                       # enough, go to allocate_here

next_location:

        addl  $HEADER_SIZE, %eax       # The total size of the memory region
        addl  %edx, %eax               # is the sum of the size that was
                                       # requested when this block was created
                                       # (currently stored in %edx), plus
                                       # another 8 bytes for the header (4 for
                                       # the Available/Unavailable flag, and 4
                                       # for the Size of the region). So,
                                       # adding %edx and $8 to %eax will get
                                       # the address of the next memory region

        jmp   alloc_loop_begin         # Go look at the next location

allocate_here:                         # If we've made it here, that means that
                                       # the region header of the region to
                                       # allocate is in %eax

        movl  $UNAVAILABLE, HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%eax)  # Mark space as unavailable

        addl  $HEADER_SIZE, %eax       # Move %eax past the header to the
                                       # usable memory (since that's what we
                                       # return)

        movl  %ebp, %esp               # Return from the function
        popl  %ebp
        ret

# If we've made it here, that means that we have exhausted all addressable
# memory, and we need to ask for more. %ebx holds the current endpoint of the
# data, and %ecx holds its size

move_to_break:                    # We need to increase %ebx to where we _want_
                                  # memory to end, so we add space for the
        addl  $HEADER_SIZE, %ebx  # headers structure and add space to the
                                  # break for the data requested
        addl  %ecx, %ebx


        # Now its time to ask Linux for more memory

        pushl %eax                # Save needed registers
        pushl %ecx
        pushl %ebx

        movl  $SYS_BRK, %eax      # Reset the break (%ebx has the requested
                                  # break point)
        int   $LINUX_SYSCALL

# Under normal conditions, this should return the new break in %eax, which will
# be either 0 if it fails, or it will be equal to or larger than we asked for.
# We don't care in this program where it actually sets the break, so as long as
# %eax isn't 0, we don't care what it is

        cmpl  $0, %eax            # Check for error conditions
        je    error

        popl  %ebx                # Restore saved registers
        popl  %ecx
        popl  %eax

        # Set this memory as unavailable, since we're about to give it away

        movl  $UNAVAILABLE, HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%eax)

        # Set the size of the memory

        movl  %ecx, HDR_SIZE_OFFSET(%eax)

        # Move %eax to the actual start of usable memory.
        # %eax now holds the return value

        addl  $HEADER_SIZE, %eax

        movl  %ebx, current_break  # Save the new break

        movl  %ebp, %esp           # Return the function
        popl  %ebp
        ret

error:

        movl  $0, %eax             # On error, we return zero
        movl  %ebp, %esp
        popl  %ebp
        ret

# allocate ends

# deallocate starts

        # PURPOSE:  The purpose of this function is to give back a region of
        #           memory to the pool after we're done using it.
        #
        # PARAMS:   The only parameter is the address of the memory we want to
        #           return to the memory pool.
        #
        # RETURN:   There is no return value
        #
        # If you remember, we actually hand the program the start of the memory
        # that they can use, which is 8 storage locations after the actual
        # start of the memory region. All we have to do is go back 8 locations
        # and mark that memory as available, so that the allocate function
        # knows it can use it.

        .globl free
        .type free,@function

        # Stack position of the memory region to free

        .equ ST_MEMORY_SEG, 4

free:

        # Since the function is so simple, we don't need any of the fancy
        # function stuff

        # Get the address of the memory to free (normally this is 8(%ebp), but
        # since we didn't push %ebp or move %esp to %ebp, we can just do
        # 4(%esp))

        movl  ST_MEMORY_SEG(%esp), %eax

        # Get the pointer to the real beginning of the memory

        subl  $HEADER_SIZE, %eax

        # Mark it as available

        movl  $AVAILABLE, HDR_AVAIL_OFFSET(%eax)

        ret

# deallocate ends
```

This is cross-compiled in a 64-bit system as follows:

```
as --32 alloc-lib.asm -o alloc-lib.o
ld --shared "-melf_i386" alloc-lib.o -o alloc-lib.so
```

However, it just results in `segfault` when I test it on a 32-bit system using something like:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./alloc-lib.so ls
```

I decided to write a simple C program to allocate an integer 1 to test it, but couldn't even make the `printf` function call. It `segfault`s too! Finally I modified the C program to dump the bytes from the new memory location to a file and validated the value using `hexdump`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int *ptra;
    char *cptra;
    ptra = malloc(4);
    *ptra = 1;
    cptra = ptra;
    putchar(*cptra);
    putchar(*(cptra + 1));
    putchar(*(cptra + 2));
    putchar(*(cptra + 3));
    free(ptra);
}
```

1. Does anyone know why does it `segfault` with `ls` and `printf`
   function call?
2. Is this test case a reasonable one?

This is a lengthy post, but I thought it is important to know how I could **test** this. As long as the `malloc` and `free` `ABI` is correct, I don't think there should be any problem right? Is there anything wrong with those assumptions?

Operating System: Linux 32 Bit

Comment: One of the potential reasons as pointed by @fuz was that I am not implementing `realloc`.

Answer (score 2):

1)  The ia32 ABI requires bx,si,di to be preserved across function calls; you assign bx in allocate_init(), and di in malloc() without preserving them.   Sometimes you can get away with not preserving registers, and sometimes you don’t.

2)  Google: will likely reveal many allocation test suites that you could apply; but since this one did point out a problem, it is a good start.

PS:  I did a visual inspection; there isn’t enough detail (os, version, ...) to reproduce.

Comment: There's isn't one single IA-32 ABI (See [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to ABI / calling-convention docs).  But yes, almost all of them agree that EBX, ESI, and EDI are call-preserved (the whole 32-bit register, not just the 16-bit sub-registers, although I think you meant that as short-hand).